# Scoring a random forest model created from parallel processing

Tags: r, random-forest, predict, parallel-foreach

I am trying to run a random forest using the foreach package for parallel processing. Here is the code i am running.

```
library(doParallel)
library(doMC)
library(foreach)
library(randomForest)

Train <- read.csv("Train_Parallel.csv")
Test <- read.csv("Test_Parallel.csv")
Scoring <- read.csv("Scoring_Parallel.csv")


cores = detectCores()-1
cl = makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

startparallel <- Sys.time()
rf_parallel <- foreach(ntree=rep(400, cores), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE,
              .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
                randomForest(target ~ .,
                             data=Train,
                             importance=TRUE,
                             ntree=ntree,
                             mtry = 25)
              }
endparallel <- Sys.time()
stopCluster(cl)
endparallel - startparallel
```

The parallel execution code runs as expected. However, when I run the predict function against my training and test dataset, I get the below error. What am I doing wrong?

```
> Train$Predicted <- predict(rf_parallel, Train)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
> Test$Predicted <- predict(rf_parallel, Test)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: `foreach` will return a single random forest model for each core. Each random forest model from each core is returned to `rf_parallel` as an element of a list. This means `rf_parallel` is a list (with length(num_cores)) with each element of the list being a random forest model. With `predict(model, data)`, it is expecting a model, not a list of models. For instance, try `predict(rf_parallel[[1]], Train)` and my guess is this will work without error. My guess is that you are misunderstanding what exactly you are parallelizing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since, I have 4 cores, there are 3 (detectCores()-1) random forest models being built with each having ntree=400.

Shouldn't ".combine=combine" combine the list into a class of "random.Forest"?

Comment: No. See what `rf_parallel` is by typing `str(rf_parallel)`. (btw, I'm not sure how to merge models, if it is even possible. You could see if the stackoverflow community has any idea.)

Comment: but then, what is the point of parallel processing if i cannot use it to score my dataset?

Comment: that is an excellent question...

Answer (score 1):

make sure randomForest::combine is not masked by dplyr::combine or something else